# How much does it cost to transition nearline storage to regional storage and then back again regularly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to keep my data in nearline and transition it to regional storage class when i need to process it.

It will need to be accessed more than once a month so it cant stay in nearline.

When I need to use it I want to switch it to regional, do a lot of reading/processing, switch back to nearline.

Is this feasible? Does it cost a lot of money to transition a storage class like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change storage classes (e.g., using the gsutil rewrite command with the -s option), for each object you would be overwriting the object with a new generation, which has three cost components:

- One or more class A operations for the chain of rewrite calls (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing for pricing)
- The storage price difference for the new storage class
- If you're going from Nearline to Regional you'll pay an early deletion fee if you're doing the rewrite before the minimum storage duration (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing)

Depending on how long your processing job runs, it might be more cost effective to simply copy all the objects to a Regional bucket, run the computation there, and then delete the objects from that bucket. Doing it that way would avoid early deletion fees, as well as the need to perform additional class A operations to rewrite the data back to the Nearline storage class. But again, whether that's more cost effective depends on how long the processing job runs, because you'll pay for two copies of the data during this time (the Nearline copy and the Regional copy).

Comment: Ah so the rewrite is totally recreating the file that makes it pointless for this use case then

Comment: @red888 - can you say more about why it would be pointless to use rewrite for this use case?

Comment: it would be too expensive i have terabytes of data

Comment: @MikeSchwartz does a rewrite (eg when going from nearline to coldline with gsutil -s coldline) also incur a data retrieval cost on the original object? The docs seem a bit contradictory on this point, with the last example stating that only the early deletion fees apply, but with a previous line stating "A retrieval cost applies when you read, copy, or rewrite data or metadata that is stored using one of these storage classes. This cost is in addition to any network charges associated with reading the data."

Comment: @Thomas Bonfort rewrite is billed as a class A operation - please see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class. So to answer your question more explicitly, it's billed as an operation, not a data retrieval. In contrast, if you were to use gsutil cp -D (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) that would be billed as a class B operation (storage.*.get) plus a retrieval, because the data are copied via the machine where gsutil is run.